# Adding items into Objects

Tags: arrays, swift, object, mklocalsearch, mklocalsearchrequest

I'm looking to be able to append a personal location into the `MKLocationSearchCompletion` `array` that will can be found when the user searches through the search bar. However, I am having trouble understanding how items are stored into objects and whether I can add a placemark object (or location information) into the `MKLocationSearch` object. What I've been able to garner from the documentation is that the `MKLocalSearchCompleter` object stores strings that are accessed when the user types in partial strings into the search bar. But I am not sure where I can access this array and add new locations.

Here is how the code is structured to display search completion results:

```
var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    searchCompleter.delegate = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
}

extension ViewController: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {
    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        searchResults = completer.results
        searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // handle error
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchResults.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let searchResult = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)

        cell.textLabel?.attributedText = highlightedText(searchResult.title, inRanges: searchResult.titleHighlightRanges, size: 17.0)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.attributedText = highlightedText(searchResult.subtitle, inRanges: searchResult.subtitleHighlightRanges, size: 12.0)

        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchText
    }

    func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that you can add your own locations and POIs to MapKit, but:

1) I would suggest you create an own enum

```
class CustomSearchResult {
    let title: String
    ...
}

enum SearchResultType {
    case localSearchResult(result: MKLocalSearchCompletion)
    case customResult(result: CustomSearchResult)
}
```

2) And you have your array of results:

```
var searchResults = [SearchResultType]()
```

3) In `completerDidUpdateResults` you can add your personal results and the MapKit results into your `searchResults` array:

```
searchResults = completer.results.map { 
   SearchResultType.localSearchResult(result: $0) }

// Add here custom results
searchResults.append(SearchResultType.customResult(result: 
    CustomSearchResult(title: "test")))
```

4) ..and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can decide whether you have custom or MapKit result:

```
let searchResult = searchResults[indexPath.row]
switch searchResult {
case .customResult(let result):
    cell.textLabel.text = result.title
case .localSearchResult(let result):
    cell.textLabel.text = result.title
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding when the switch statement is executed. When cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, each row of the tableview will execute the switch statement right? I am able to append a .customResult into searchResults; however when I am searching with the search bar, the custom result does not show up.